# Swift two table view cell get the same value

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have used a tableview with 16 cells on a view controller. Each cell has a textfield and a picker view as a inputview for textfield. The odd thing is that When I choose the value for the first cell, it's fine. When I scrolled down to the last cell, the value is same as the first one. But I have never touched the last cell. Why would this happened?

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    // selected value in Uipickerview in Swift
    answerText.text = pickerDataSource[row]
    answerText.tag = row
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addFollowCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddFollowTableViewCell
    cell.questionView.text = listQuestion1[indexPath.row]
    cell.pickerDataSource = dictPicker[indexPath.row]!
    cell.answerText.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AddFollowUpViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidEnd)
    return cell
}

func textFieldDidChange(sender: UITextField){
    let rowIndex: Int!
    let selectValue = sender.tag

    if let txtf = sender as? UITextField {
        if let superview = txtf.superview {
            if let cell = superview.superview as? AddFollowTableViewCell {
                rowIndex = myTable.indexPathForCell(cell)?.row
                dictAnswer[rowIndex] = selectValue - 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After two days, it solved by thousands of trials:

```
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addFollowCell") as! AddFollowTableViewCell
    if(cell.identifier == true){
        cell.answerText.text = selectedAnswerForRow[indexPath.row]
    }
    cell.questionView.text = listQuestion1[indexPath.row]
    cell.pickerDataSource = dictPicker[indexPath.row]!
    dictAnswer[indexPath.row] = cell.pickerValue
    cell.answerText.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AddFollowUpViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidEnd)
    cell.identifier = true

  return cell
}

func textFieldDidChange(sender: UITextField){
    let rowIndex: Int!
    let cell = sender.superview?.superview as! AddFollowTableViewCell
    rowIndex = myTable.indexPathForCell(cell)?.row
    selectedAnswerForRow[rowIndex] = cell.answerValue
    print(selectedAnswerForRow[rowIndex])
    cell.answerText.text = sender.text
    cell.identifier = true

}
```

It might have some performance issue need to be optimised , but it shows exactly what i want. LOL

Comment: How many sections do you have in your `UITableView`?

Comment: Just One section in my table.

Answer (score 2):

You're basically recycling your views and not clearing them. That's the whole point of `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:indexPath:`.

Allocating and deallocating memory is very power consuming, so the system recycles every cell that goes out of viewport bounds.

You don't set the text inside `answerText` *(I assume it's the text field that causes trouble)* so its content will be kept when recycled.

Assuming you'll store user selection inside a dictionary `var selectedAnswerForRow: [IndexPath:String]`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addFollowCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddFollowTableViewCell
    cell.questionView.text = listQuestion1[indexPath.row]
    cell.pickerDataSource = dictPicker[indexPath.row]!
    cell.answerText.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidEnd)
    cell.answerText.text = self.selectedAnswerForRow[indexPath] ?? "" // add this
    return cell
}
```

`self.selectedAnswerForRow[indexPath] ?? ""` returns the result or an empty string if it's not present in the dictionary.

---

Also, you're adding several times the action for edition control event. You have to check first if it isn't already bound.

Comment: self.selectedAnswerForRow[indexPath] ? When I tried that, it gives me an error that my controller has no member of selectedAnswerForRow

Comment: You have to create this property inside your controller, just add the line `var selectedAnswerForRow: [IndexPath:String] = []` at the beginning of your view controller class declaration. You also have to store the results inside it, from `textFieldDidChange ` for example. But that's just one way to store your answers, not the best. I think you should be able to find a more convenient way to store them. The idea is to store every textfield content somewhere else because there's only a limited number of cells created.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But a new problem is  the first cell would be set to nil when I scrolled up to top.

Comment: That's the use of `selectedAnswerForRow`, to store answers as you select them for each row and restore them when cells are presented.

Comment: I have used that, but I dont know why it has not store the picked value.

Comment: Did you changed your code inside `textFieldDidChange:` to store the answers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112423/discussion-between-crazyrems-and-janice-zhan).

Answer (score 0):

Because the cell is reused. So you have to implement `prepareForReuse()` in your custom cell class and reset all the changing variables

**UPDATE**

See :

```
class MyCell : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTextField : UITextField!

    //Add the following
    override func prepareForReuse() {
    myTextField.text = nil
    myTextField.inputView = myPickerView
    super.prepareForReuse()
   }
}
```

Comment: What does rest all changing variables mean? Can you give me a code to explain it? Thanks

Comment: don't forget to flag answer if it did help you ;)

Comment: Hmmmm. Now it wont repeat the choice.But another problem is that when I scrolled up to top, the first picker has been set to nil.

Comment: where did you set your picker as the textfield's inputView ?

Comment: The picker view and textfield both in cell

Comment: re-set it in the prepareForReuse too.

Comment: Should I reset the pickerview datasource or other something? Sorry, I am new to swift.

Comment: No, you should not. But you should not addTarget in cellForRow either. Each time a cell is displayed, you add a new target. So if you scroll enough, you will have 100 target called for your event. think to removeAllTarget before adding a new one

Comment: I tried but failed.   cell.answerText.removeTarget(self, action: nil, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.AllEvents)
        cell.answerText.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AddFollowUpViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidEnd)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112474/discussion-between-bobby-and-janice-zhan).